# In what format, should enums be printed? %what?

Tags: objective-c, enums

This line of code causes compiler to complain and enter a debug mode

```
NSLog(@"Attacker card: %@", [attackerCard suit]);
```

I wonder whether it is due to the fact that suit is an `enum` value declared as

```
@property (assign) Suit suit;
```

Where `Suit` is declared as

```
typedef enum {
    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES
} Suit;
```

Am i doing something wrong with the format or, the problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: Use and int format like %d and cast the enum as (int). Without casting I cannot avoid a warning in XCode 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific size of an enumerated type is implementation defined but it's always an integer type, so `%d` will work most of the time.  If you need it to be very robust, you'll want to test `sizeof(Suit)` and choose a format based on that.

Comment: Thank you Carl! Is there a way for me to recover "text representation" of particular enum value. In other words, can i do something to get "HEARTS" instead of 2?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that without making your own lookup table.